# Understanding of a logistic regression example

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Logistic regression. The following is from package mypc example 
project. It is still unclear to me for its purpose. More specifically, 
variable n is [5, 5, 5, 5], which is used in the mode: pymc.Binomial.

I suppose it should have both 0 and 1 in binomial fitting. n is to represent 
'1' cases?

Could you explain the idea of this example? Thanks,

The example is from: 
www.map.ox.ac.uk/media/PDF/Patil_et_al_2010.pdf

.........

```
import pymc 
import numpy as np 

n = 5*np.ones(4,dtype=int) 
x = np.array([-.86,-.3,-.05,.73]) 

alpha = pymc.Normal('alpha',mu=0,tau=.01) 
beta = pymc.Normal('beta',mu=0,tau=.01) 

@pymc.deterministic 
def theta(a=alpha, b=beta): 
    """theta = logit^{-1}(a+b)""" 
    return pymc.invlogit(a+b*x) 

d = pymc.Binomial('d', n=n, p=theta, value=np.array([0.,1.,3.,5.]),\ 
                    observed=True) 
....... 

import pymc 
import pymc.Matplot 
import mymodel 

S = pymc.MCMC(mymodel, db='pickle') 
S.sample(iter=10000, burn=5000, thin=2) 
pymc.Matplot.plot(S) 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.show()
```